# How to download HTTRACK on my computer?

Tags: software-installation

`httrack` is a program so that you can copy a website. I downloaded the file from their website for linux based computers and then extracted the files but now if I go and look for the file. I can't run the program or anything, it just appears as a bunch of random files such as `html`, `lang`, `libtest`, etc…

How can I actually run the file? Im a newbie to linux so please give simple instructions.

Comment: I would read the guides they have posted on the site: https://www.httrack.com/html/fcguide.html And httrack is in the repository so why go all the trouble of compiling it? ;)

Answer (score 12):

If you do not know that you can find the source code in this directory, then you'd better install the package via `apt` with this command

```sh
sudo apt-get install httrack
```

and all is fine and you can start httrack via terminal to download the internet **;)**

```sh
httrack "http://www.google.com/" -O "/tmp/www.google.com"
```

No, sorry, replace `google.com` with your target URL.

---

The hard way:

1. Install a helper

   ```sh
   sudo apt-get install checkinstall
   ```
2. Compile and install

   ```sh
   cd
   wget http://download.httrack.com/httrack-3.48.21.tar.gz
   tar xf httrack-3.48.21.tar.gz
   cd httrack-3.48.21
   ./configure
   make
   sudo checkinstall
   ```

   You could also use `sudo make install` instead of `sudo checkinstall`.

Comment: i Tried the first one but the terminal came back with this: no command 'httrack' found, did you mean: Command 'httrack' from package 'httrack' (main).  UPDATE: I now tried it with instead of 'httrack' i tried 'httrack main' and that seemed to work. But then it said it was copying the website and then ended after 2 seconds and said it was complete. Where would i find the saved copied website and surely that was too quick to copy the whole website

Answer (score 7):

As more than an alternative you can use `wget` to retrieve remote web pages.

`wget` is a treasure. You can do lots of things you can't imagine.

I also tried `httrack` in the past, it's my favorite in Windows platform. When I switched to Ubuntu I also tried it again but it was not I expected then I happened to know merits of `wget`. I made myself a `.bashrc` command which I use it frequently.

```sh
crwl() {
    wget --tries=inf --timestamping --recursive --level=inf --convert-links --page-requisites --no-parent "$@"
}
```

Copy above function into your `.bashrc` 
Then source your `.bashrc` file from your terminal in user directory or logout and login.

```sh
source .bashrc
```

It's my function as it is, you can modify it to your needs.

You can use it like this:

```sh
crwl www.site.com/somelink
```

---

Further resources:

- [Manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget)
- [Advanced functions and tutorials](http://www.labnol.org/software/wget-command-examples/28750/)

Answer (score 1):

**Stable packages**

**to get the full GUI version**

apt-get update

apt-get install webhttrack

**or to get the commandline version only**

apt-get update

apt-get install httrack

[Source](http://debian.httrack.com/)

Answer (score 0):

While using Linux Platforms prefer **wget** instead of httrack.
wget or web get downloads files over a network.It is non interactive(works in background).

The following command would download the files in current working directory.
wget http://website.com/files/file.zip

This image can help you understand the usage of command 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfu2j.jpg